# Best front-end for GAE Google App Engine in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, frontend

**which is the best front-end solution for a GAE app. developed in Go?**

best:=
the question is about choosing a solution that merges well with the GAE, as an example if I use GAE in Java I would pick up GWT, and I want to know how other people are using the GAE with Go;

why this question:=
the reason I'm asking this is that I want to understand if, today, there is an advisable path to follow in designing a web application that uses GAE with go when I have to choose something for the front-end ..and I'm trying to figure it out before digging into a useless 'reinventing the wheel coding mode'.

Comment: Probably... [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)! :o

Comment: the question is about choosing a solution that merges well with the GAE, as an example if I use GAE in java I would pick up GWT, and I want to know how other people are using the GAE with Go; this is what I associate with "best"

Comment: You should then articulate this more by editing the question accordingly! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [Gorilla web toolkit](http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/), is has been designed with App Engine in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint! I am having a look at it right now